# задачка fizzbuzz для знатоков

Tags: python

Как решить задачку fizzbuzz в одну строчку кода?

Описание задачи:

> Выведите строкой через пробел числа от 1 до 100, но со следующими заменами: если число делится на 3, то замените на fizz, если на 5 - на buzz, если число делится и на 3 и на 5 то на fizzbuzz.

Пример кода:

```
result_1 = []
for n in range(1, 101):
    if n % 15 == 0:
        result_1.append(f+b)
        continue
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        result_1.append(b)
        continue
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        result_1.append(f)
    else:
        result_1.append(n)
print ' '.join(map(str, result_1))
```

Comment: сайт предназначен для поиска ответов на конкретные вопросы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Python:**

```
print([((not i%3) * 'Fizz' + (not i%5) * 'Buzz') or i for i in range (1, 101)], sep=' ')
```

Comment: приятно видеть, что искал

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*['fizzbuzz' if i%15 == 0 else 'fizz' if i%3 == 0 else 'buzz' if i%5 == 0 else i for i in range(100)])
```